# Rock-Paper-Scissors but rock scores double

Tags: mathematics, game-theory

Suppose two perfect game theorists play rock paper scissors. Scoring is slightly different:

- 2 points when beating scissors with rock
- 1 point when beating rock with paper
- 1 point when beating paper with scissors

In case of a tie or loss, 0 points are awarded.

Assuming both players play an infinite number of games and both play optimally, what random distribution would give the highest expected score per game?

Comment: @bobble You want to still pick one of rock, paper, or scissors at random, though probably not with a uniform distribution like the normal game. Yes highest for one player

Comment: Doesn't literally any distribution that has a non-zero probability for each of the throws have an infinite expected score?

Comment: Do you only want answers that are a random distribution? There are non-random strategies that achieve a higher score per game.

Comment: If there is no Nash equilibrium, then there could be no single distribution that wins, right? (finding out whether there is a Nash equilibrium does seem part of the question)

Comment: @justhalf Any non-random distribution is exploitable by an opponent

Comment: Is a player trying to maximize her score or to maximize the difference between her score and her opponent's ?

Comment: @Evargalo Given two ideal players the expected difference is always going to be zero.

Comment: @fljx : but the definition of "ideal player" depends on the role they are assigned. If their goal is to maximize the difference, the expected difference is zero ; if their goal is to maximize each individual score, it might differ.

Comment: To make it a zero-sum game and avoid prisonner's dilemma to be a thing (which can make it tricky/impossible to solve), you may want to say that :
"You lose 1 point when losing against paper or scissors and you lose 2 points when losing against rock".
Only then the goal to maximize your points and the goal to maximize the difference with the opponent is the same.

Answer (score 19):

This probably isn't the answer you want but:

> Given that the players are equally "perfect", they can both expect to gain exactly half the total points scored in the long run. This is true whether their strategies are matched or distinct.
>
>  So, the best strategy for both players to maximise their expected score per game, is to co-operatively maximise the total score.
>
>  This can be achieved by both players alternating between scissors and rock, one starting with rock, the other starting with scissors. That will gain them both an average score of 1 per game.

Comment: This is called "[Superrationality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superrationality)", a term coined by Douglas Hostadter.

Comment: Yep, good point about symmetry. Also note that this strategy is true even if the scores are all the same (1 point for any win, 0 otherwise). With uniform distribution in the same score case, expected score per game is 1/3, but with this strategy, it's 1/2. If we're assuming OP is asking to find something that's the best in the same way uniform is the best for the same score case, the best average score is 4/9, which is half of the total average score per game (8/9), and uninterestingly, still achieved with uniform..

Comment: I think technically this answer is correct, but I think it takes the question too literally. The question should also include that you want to score more points than your opponent, or assign negative points to losing players. Taking it as a cooperative game renders the question trivial.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks This answers the question as asked. The point here is that this isn't a zero-sum game. 1 win + 1 loss is better for both players than 2 draws, and co-operation is the optimal way to achieve that consistently over the long run. If you think the question should have been different, you're always free to ask your own.

Comment: @fljx I already acknowledged that. I'm just wondering why an obvious answer to an obvious question receives so many upvotes. Also I think re-asking the question in the correct way would be closed as duplicate, because that answer is also already here.

Comment: @fljx - This probably isn't the comment you want, but the question asks "what random distribution", and this isn't a random distribution.

Comment: @GlenO I asked when the question appeared whether to he OP *only* wanted random distributions and never got a response.

Comment: @fljx The term "zero-sum game" doesn't refer to number of points. Basketball is a zero-sum game, even though two teams could collude to get hundreds of points.

Comment: It's quite likely that this is not just the superrational solution but also a Nash equilibrium (though not the only Nash equilibrium) - see the discussion under James Martin's answer.

Comment: @Acccumulation But that's because basketball is ultimately scored in terms of games, not points, so it doesn't matter that points are not zero-sum. Here OP makes it clear that points are the final unit of scoring.

Comment: @N.Virgo it certainly isn't a Nash equilibrium, since if your opponent is alternating rock-scissors, your best strategy is to alternate paper-rock. Any predictable strategy can always be beaten.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime I wasn't precise enough. I explained it better in the comments under James Martin's answer. The Nash equilibrium is that each player plays the strategy in this answer *unless* the other player ever deviates, in which case they switch to playing the strategy described in James Martin's answer, forever. That way each player is disincentivised to cheat, because although they'll gain a higher payoff in the next round they will have a lower expected payoff in all future rounds. That this sort of thing can happen is called the "folk theorem" in game theory.

Comment: @N.Virgo Ah, I see, thank you and apologies!

Answer (score 16):

> The unique Nash equilibrium is where both players play Rock, Paper, Scissors with probabilities $(r,p,s)=(\frac{2}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{5})$. In this equilibrium each player wins on average $\frac{2}{5}$ points per turn.

> If you know your opponent is following some distribution $(r,p,s)$, then the expected values of your options Rock, Paper, Scissors are $2s$, $p$, and $r$ respectively. These are all equal if and only if $(r,p,s)=(\frac{2}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{5})$.

> For a Nash equilibrium, we should have that your distribution is an optimal response to your opponent's, and the opponent's distribution is an optimal response to yours. Suppose some Nash equilibrium where your distribution is not $(\frac{2}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{5})$. Then your opponent's strategy would give weight 0 to at least one option, call it A. From this we deduce that your strategy gives weight $0$ to the option that beats A, call it B. In turn we get that the opponent's strategy gives weight $0$ to the third option, C. Continuing this line of argument one can quickly reach a contradiction.

Comment: If both players play uniform distribution, the average score per turn is 4/9, which is larger than 2/5, so this strategy doesn't beat the uniform distribution, at least.

Comment: @justhalf Yes, if both players agree to play uniform distribution, then the average score per turn is 4/9. Even better, if both players agree to alternate between the outcomes (Scissors, Rock) and (Rock, Scissors) then the average score per turn is 1! So the players can profit by collaborating. But neither situation gives a Nash equilibrium. If you do play uniform distribution, then a rational opponent will play Rock against you every time (giving them 2/3 per turn and you 1/3 per turn).

Comment: Ah, good point! Maybe you can include that into your answer as well.

Comment: +1, since this answers the question given, but this assumes the players play independently, without memory of previous games - if this is an iterated game it might change things quite a bit.

Comment: @N.Virgo As the answer explains, this solution hits the [Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium). That means that the strategy is optimal in the sense that whichever player chooses to deviate will start losing more. So even in the long run, and with perfect memory, it is best for both players to stick with the given strategy.

Comment: The Nash equilibrium of the "stage" game is also an equilibrium of the repeated game, yes. But @N.Virgo is right that there are other equilibria of the repeated game, as in my answer!

Comment: @Bass usul's comment is what I meant. Things can change quite a lot when you turn a game into an iterated game. For example, "always defect" is a Nash equilibrium of the iterated prisoner's dilemma, but there are many others. In particular, if both players play [tit for tat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_for_tat) then they will both cooperate on every single round, and this is a Nash equilibrium of the iterated game. (Although admittedly not a subgame perfect equilibrium.)

Comment: Indeed, I suspect the strategy in fljx's answer is a Nash equilibrium of the iterated game as well, since if either player deviates the other player can punish them by playing this strategy (choose uniformly with probabilities 2/5,2/5,1/5) for the rest of time. (Does that sound plausible to you, @usul?)

Comment: @N.Virgo yes, I think the Folk Theorem will apply there too, and the same reasoning as you say! Link for convenience: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_theorem_%28game_theory%29

Comment: isn't it also a draw at 2/5 if the opponent only plays rock?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things we could mean by "both play optimally". Here's an interesting one.

By the

> [folk theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_theorem_%28game_theory%29),

there are many different

> Nash equilibria of the repeated game,

including where one player

> has average utility almost $2 - \frac{2}{5}$, and the other just over $\frac{2}{5}$.

Here's how it works:

> The first player will play rock four rounds in a row, then scissors, and repeat this pattern. The second player will play scissors four rounds in a row, then rock, and repeat. But on rounds 1,11,101,1001,..., they will also swap and the second player will play rock. The first player's average utility is almost $\frac{8}{5} = 2 - \frac{2}{5}$. The second player's average utility is just over $\frac{2}{5}$. The swap rounds, which get rarer and rarer, only have a vanishing impact on the utilities.
>
>  Why would the second player agree to this? Because if they ever deviate from this plan (for example play paper on round they aren't supposed to), the first player has committed to switch to always playing the randomization $(2/5, 2/5, 1/5)$. That will give both players exactly $\frac{2}{5}$ expected utility for the rest of the games. So the second player would rather go along with the plan and get a tiny bit more than that than deviate.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So even in this symmetric (albeit non-zero sum) game, the Nash equilibirium can involve different outcome for each player? I learn something new today. Thanks for the reference to the folk theorem

Comment: @justhalf The issue is that usul is treating "the game" as the entire sequence of plays. If we look at the Nash Equilibrium of a single round, then it's completely symmetric. It's only when we allow "Blackmail your opponents with threats regarding what you'll do on further rounds" as a strategy that non-symmetric Nash Equilibria appear.

Comment: @Acccumulation the strategy is indeed utilizing a threat on future rounds. I'm just wondering why fljx argument doesn't work here (i.e., any player can use the same strategy). So the one who wins is the one who threaten "first" outside the game or something?

Comment: I.e., what prevents anyone to want to be the one getting the higher score? Something like, A: I play like this, you play like that so I get 4/3-, you get 2/3+., B: No! I want to be the one getting 4/3-! A: Sure, but I'll then play the 2/3 strategy. We'll both lose! B: So am I! If you're not giving me what I want, I also gonna play 2/3 strategy! You'll lose as well if you don't give me what I want. A: But you'll also lose if you don't give me what I want! [So, what's next?]

Comment: @justhalf this is a peculiarity of how Nash equilibrium works. We can pretend someone else tells both players what they are supposed to play. In this case, the first player is supposed to get most of the utility and threaten to deviate, and the second player is supposed to go along with it. Given that, each player would rather follow the instructions than deviate. There are different Nash equilibrium, some where the second player gets a lot more. But how we negotiate which equilibrium to play ... is a whole other question :)

Comment: @justhalf A Nash equilibrium is a pair of strategies such that each player can't do better, given the other player's strategy. If the first player is sure that the second player will give in to the threat, then the best the first player can do is to take advantage of that. If the second player can convince the first player that they aren't going to give in, then the first player will change their strategy. Note that Nash equilibria aren't necessarily unique. So the symmetry isn't really broken: there's *another* Nash equilibria where the second player threaten the first.

Comment: Here's another game to consider: there are ten dollars on a table. Both players write down how many they want. If what they write down is less than or equal to ten, then they both get what they asked for. If it's more, then both get nothing. One Nash equilibrium is both ask for \$5. Another is that one asks for \$9 and the other asks for \$1. *If* the first player always asks for \$9, then the second can't do any better than asking for \$1.

Comment: @usul thanks, your last phrase is very clear to me "how we negotiate which Nash equilibria to play is a whole other question". So picking which equilibria is not part of the strategy space where Nash equilibria is taking place.

Answer (score 2):

If this is 0-sum and points won by the winner are lost by the loser,

> Throw paper with probability 0.5, rock with probability 0.25 and scissors with probability 0.25. Then regardless of your opponent's strategy your expected winnings are 0. Since the game is symmetric, this can't be beaten.

Comment: "_In case of a tie or loss, 0 points are awarded_" implies it's not zero-sum. I don't know if this changes you analysis.

Comment: @R.M. it does change the analysis, in that it unfortunately makes it wrong

Answer (score 1):

> The expected value of each throw is EV=2P(R)Q(S) + P(P)Q(R) + P(S)Q(P) where P(x) is the probability that we choose x as our throw and Q(x) is the probability our opponent chooses x as their throw. I take our opponent playing optimally to mean that they will be able to exploit our strategy to maximize their EV, so what we'd really like is that the expected value of each of our throws to be the same regardless of what our opponent throws.

> This is done by setting 2P(R) = P(P) = P(S), or a 20% chance of throwing rock, and a 40% chance of throwing each of paper and scissors. This simplifies our EV equation to EV = .4(Q(S)+Q(R)+Q(P)) = .4

Comment: Shouldn’t we consider negative values for the case our opponent wins?

Comment: @Jujustum I don't think so, since we are looking for highest score and not highest score differential

Comment: The optimal response to this strategy is to play rock every time with an expected score of .8, so I don't think it is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

- Only opponent may adapt strategy: see [James Martin's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/124669/70260).
- Only you may adapt strategy: see [James Martin's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/124669/70260). (opponent should use that strategy)
- Both may adapt strategy: see [fljx's answer.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/124665/70260)
- Both Logicians may not adapt their strategy (and cooperate for maximum equal score):

> gain: $2rs+pr+sp$
>  $rs$ is the biggest source of points, it should be increased.
>  For $r+s$ constant, the profit is at maximum if $r=s$, so we can use that
>  gain: $2rr + (1-2r)r + r(1-2r)$
>  maximum $2r-2rr$ is at $r =0.5$
>  $(r,p,s)= (1/2,0,1/2)\implies$ expected profit is equal to $0.5$